# ng-model binding not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to append some html for each element of an array. I found this solution to do it but when I'm trying to update the ng-model dynamically through javascript the inputs are never updating.

I'm trying to solve my problem like this:

javascript:

```
var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('.change'));
        $scope.rowsSelected=($('#querytable').DataTable().rows('.selected').data());
        for(var i = 0; i<$('#querytable').DataTable().rows('.selected').data().length; i++){
            $scope.dataSelected.push($('#querytable').DataTable().rows('.selected').data()[i]);
            divElement.append('<form name="formChooseAdress" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate><div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label>Fatura: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ff_'+i+'" ng-model="model_firstField_'+i+'" disabled></div><div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label>Valor total: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fs_'+i+'" ng-model="model_secondField_'+i+'" disabled></div><div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label>Valor a pagar: </label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="ft_'+i+'" ng-model="model_thirdField_'+i+'" max="model_secondField_'+i+'" min="0"></div><br><br><br><p></p></form>');
            var a="model_firstField_";
            var b="model_secondField_";
            var c="model_thirdField_";

            var d=i;
            var res=a.concat(d);
            var res1=b.concat(d);
            var res2=c.concat(d);

            $scope[res]= $scope.dataSelected[i].chosen;
            $scope[res1]= $scope.dataSelected[i].chosen1;
            $scope[res2]= $scope.dataSelected[i].chosen2;
        };
        $scope.$apply();
```

This code appears inside an modal that has a div with a id change.

Modal html code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="changeCA" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Changes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <label>Data: </label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tp" ng-model="model_tp">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="change">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"
                        ng-click="next()">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i display the value ?

Comment: Mixing jQuery with AngularJS like this is asking for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not good practice to use jQuery like this within AngularJS controllers. However I can see the problem you are facing is because you are not `Compiling` html which angular understand. Just use `$compile` service to compile your html string before appending to DOM. You will see that `ng-model` will be updating.

Inject `$compile` to your controller and try below code.

```
var template = $compile('<form name="formChooseAdress" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate><div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label>Fatura: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ff_'+i+'" ng-model="model_firstField_'+i+'" disabled></div><div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label>Valor total: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fs_'+i+'" ng-model="model_secondField_'+i+'" disabled></div><div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-4"><label>Valor a pagar: </label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="ft_'+i+'" ng-model="model_thirdField_'+i+'" max="model_secondField_'+i+'" min="0"></div><br><br><br><p></p></form>')($scope, function(clonedElement, scope) { divElement.append(template); });
```

[Read more about $compile here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: i already injected the $compile but know i'm getting this error : 

Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=scope&p1=required

do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Show your code, how are you injecting `$compile`. There must be something wrong.

Comment: Javascript: app.controller('Changectrl', function ($scope,  $compile, $http){}

HTML: <div ng-controller="Changectrl" id="all" ng-init="getData();">

Comment: This looks ok. I can see the above error you pasted is not related to `$compile` it's something with scope. Click on that error and see where you did wrong with scope. Maybe you wrote `scope` insted of $scope

Comment: But if i comment the 2 lines of your solution the error disappears . And there is no $scope on it.

Comment: Try updated answer. Ref - https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/docs/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Great! As you're new to stackoverflow. It's good to give upvote and select right answer to encourage others.